# MQL4 "undeclared identifier" - how can I fix this issue?

Tags: variables, algorithmic-trading, mql4

I'm currently trying to learn a programming language called **`MQL4`**, which is used to write trading algorithms. It is very closely based on `C++/C/C#`, so anyone with knowledge of these languages should be able to help me out with this one.

I'm trying to create a very simple program which tells me the length of the upper and lower shadows (wicks) of the last periods candlestick. To do this, I've tried using the following code:

```
  double    bod1 = Close[1] - Open[1];
  double absbod1 = MathAbs( bod1 );

  if( bod1 >= 0 )
  {
  double uwick1 = High[1] - Close[1];
  double lwick1 = Open[1] - Low[  1];
  }
  else
  {
  double uwick1 = High[ 1] - Open[1];
  double lwick1 = Close[1] - Low[ 1];
  }

  Alert( "Lower Wick: " , lwick1 , " Upper Wick: " , uwick1 );
```

**Q1:** Why does this give the following error message?

[image: error]

**Q2:** Can you not define variables within an **`if(){...}`** statement?

**Q3:** If not, how can I define a variable which depends on some other factor?

I mean, suppose that I wanted to define the variable ***var*** such that ***var = a*** OR ***var = b*** depending on whether `a > b` or not.

**Q4:** How would I do this, if not by using `if(){...}` statements, as shown above?

Comment: Turn to the subsection covering variable scope in your text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that language is similar to c++ then you should define your variable before if block, ex:

```
  double uwick1 = 0;
  if(bod1 >=0)
  {
     uwick1 = High[1]-Close[1];
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error, but does not solve the problem. It seems that when I change the code to what you've said, it still uses whatever value of uwick1 and lwick1 comes before the if statement.

Comment: @user2910074: Note that in this code, the assignment in the `if` block does _NOT_ have the word `double`.  If the word `double` is there, it makes a new variable with the same name, assigns it, and ignores the outer variable.  In marcinj's code, it's merely assigning, not making a new variable.

Comment: @marcinj your initial assumption is not correct. Your post does not provide answers for Q3 + Q4

Answer (score 1):

In languages similar to C++, a variable defined in a block only exists inside that block.

So in your code:

```
double bod1 = Close[1]-Open[1];
double absbod1 = MathAbs(bod1);

if(bod1 >=0)
{
    double uwick1 = High[1]-Close[1];
    double lwick1 = Open[1]-Low[1];
}
else
{
    double uwick1 = High[1]-Open[1];
    double lwick1 = Close[1]-Low[1];
}

Alert("Lower Wick: " , lwick1 , " Upper Wick: " , uwick1);
```

A `uwick1` variable is defined in the `if` block and then goes out of scope. Another `uwick1` variable is defined in the `else` block and then goes out of scope. Finally, the `Alert` call references a `uwick1` variable, but there aren't any variables in scope with that name.

If you define the variables *before* the conditional:

```
double bod1 = Close[1]-Open[1];
double absbod1 = MathAbs(bod1);

double uwick1;
double lwick1;
if(bod1 >=0)
{
    uwick1 = High[1]-Close[1];
    lwick1 = Open[1]-Low[1];
}
else
{
    uwick1 = High[1]-Open[1];
    lwick1 = Close[1]-Low[1];
}

Alert("Lower Wick: " , lwick1 , " Upper Wick: " , uwick1);
```

This code should work the way you expected.

Answer (score 0):

### While
**`MQL4`** may look like a C-language,
beware it is not
  <sub>( +
it has a pair of compilation-modes
that have VERY DIFFERENT code-execution of the SAME SOURCE CODE
... so Devil is hidden in details
)</sub>

Your inital notes about similarity can and will cause a lot of troubles down the road.

Forget about **`C`**.

An anxient Assembler directive is worth repeating **`#ASSUME NOTHING`**

> **`string`** is not a `string`, but a special case of **`struct`** and the list of differences grows.

**`MQL4`** simply is not a C-language.

The sooner one realises, the better.

**First,**
the language's execution model is subordinated in three, very different models:
- in the <kbd>`MQL4 Script`</kbd> -- disconnected from asynchronous external **`FxMarketEventSTREAM`**
- in the <kbd>`MQL4 Expert Advisor`</kbd> -- a code-execution is edge-triggered by `FxMarketEventSTREAM`
- in the <kbd>`MQL4 Custom Indicator`</kbd> -- a code-execution is (sub)-batch-run once edge-triggered by `FxMarketEventSTREAM`

This is something none of the C-language has built-in.

**Second**,
the language syntax evolves ( better to say, it creeps ) and new constraints start to apply. The only method how to cope with this is to re-read **`MQL4` Documentation** literally on **each and every update**, yes, on each and every update. One may avoid unwanted surprises by this step ( still more suprises remain to become visible after compilation -- needles to say, that some parts of provided documentation is clearly wrong, some remain clear, until you compile the "compliant"-code and it gets rejected by compiler/parser. The worst comes on cases, that magically "pass"-through the compiler/parser phase and remain causing you nightmares on runtime, where the crippled code does strange things, that still passed all compilation/execution restrictions, but produce havoc  <sub>( sure, another story, but posted for complete warning about the `MQL4`-ecosystem risks and danger-zones -- so forget about C-language, your cruelest enemy is inside MetaQuotes Language revisions ( *New-*`MQL4.56789...` ) evolution )</sub>

### *New-*`MQL4.56789`
has introduced dual-compilation mode -- a `#strict` and an *"old"*

One of the ***"New"*** changes ( that has caused a cost of a few man*years of code-base re-design ) is a limited variable scope. Besides a dual globally-scoped variable construct, the *"New"-*`MQL4.56789` started to "frame" a visibility of a declared variable so that "outside" the "outer" constructor of such variable, the symbol ceases to exist and is thus undefined, as your compile-time error reports.

> **Q1:** is solved, the `if(){...}else{...}` were the limits for both pair of declarations ( bracketed parts `{...}` were the two, adjacent scopes, where `double`s were defined & "visible" ) and your original code, outside of the `{...}`-zone tried to reference a symbol, that was not "known" outside the declaration-scope, so the compiler had to report that as **`"- undefined identifier"`** as it had no clue what the identifier should stand for.

**Q2:** Yes, one can define variables within an `if(){...}` statement. Such variables remain defined "inside" the scope of theirs `{...}`-outer-block. One may benefit from another architecture feature -- a declaration modifier **`static`**. This will maintain a code-execution-time persistency of a value of such defined variable during the whole lifecycle of the code runtime environment and whenever a code-execution path re-enters the variable's `{...}`-visibility scope, it's value ) upon each re-entry remains re-stored for re-use.

> **Q3+Q4:** **Declaring** a variable is a principally important step and **assigment** of a value is another one. Having said this, one may observe problems once trying to declare+assign values in one single step. There a dependency may create problems for compiler -- in some previous `MQL4`-Builds this was the case -- that compiler was asked to solve an undecideable problem, when the assignment was dependent ( on other variable(s), as you name it ) on some operations / values that were not available at compile-time. Your motivation is clear and doable, however please try to design your code with this little level insights into the syntax-specifications and the principal differences between a code-compilation and a code-execution states.

---

> **Epilogue:** Don't panic & Enjoy the worlds of algorithmic trading.